# Some Punycode URLs redirect to Unicode but others don't, why?

Tags: subdomain, unicode, punycode

I've setup two subdomains, each using punycode:

http://xn--xxa.hawx.me/ -> http://μ.hawx.me/
http://xn--l6h.hawx.me/ -> http://♪.hawx.me/

If you visit the unicode versions, ♪.hawx.me will stay the same in the browser bar but μ.hawx.me will redirect to the punycode version. Why does this happen and is it possible to force it to stay as the μ version when visited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on whether or not the TLD supports unicode. TLDs that do will be converted, TLDs that don't, won't.

In my browser (FireFox 3.6) neither of them stay in unicode, they both get converted to punycode, which I would suspect is the correct behaviour for `.me`

Comment: Thanks, I've been looking into it and I think it's because μ looks like a u so could be open to phishing, etc. And then there is of course the fact different browsers do different things as you pointed out.